Disable/Hide top bar clock Ubuntu 22.04.04
I would really like to disable/hide the clock at the center of the top bar of gnome
I am running GNOME Shell 42.9 on Ubuntu 22.04.04
things I tried -> installing and enabling the hideclock extension (this doesnt work anymore and does nothing since the Ubuntu 22.04 update)
create my own hideclock extension (failed)
set all clock css in the gnome shell theme to 0px (failed)
using tweaks (only options are avilable to disable day and seconds but not the hours and minutes) (failed)
If there is a way to disable or hide the clock in Ubuntu 22.04.04 at the top bar completely(hours and minutez) I would appreciate it

Extension Manager has an extension Panel Date Format which is for GNOME versions 3.36 upwards to v44. When installed, click on the cog wheel and clear the contents of the Format tab. I haven't tried this but you may wish to. (I'm perfectly happy with my date set up as it is). I thik you can also achieve similar with GNOME Extensions in Firefox.
